# How do I get a specific element from a json string?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have a JSON string (not in a file): `[{'x': 403.5, 'y': 53.0, 'width': 117, 'height': 106, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.626}, {'x': 446.0, 'y': 189.0, 'width': 124, 'height': 130, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.528}]`, now as you can see, the entire string is in a list. Inside the list is the dictionary. There are 2 dictionaries in the list and I want to get how many dictionaries there are (it's only 2 for this example) and I want to get the `'confidence'` values of both of them. They aren't in a file, just in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d_list = [{'x': 403.5, 'y': 53.0, 'width': 117, 'height': 106, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.626}, {'x': 446.0, 'y': 189.0, 'width': 124, 'height': 130, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.528}]
confidence_vals = [d['confidence'] for d in d_list]
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to create a plain object from the string representation and getting the `length` property of the array for free. Or reduce the array to get the sum of confidences.

[PyNative JSON parsing](https://pynative.com/python-json-load-and-loads-to-parse-json/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the value, you can slice the list and get the value of the key from each list index:

```
lst = [{'x': 403.5, 'y': 53.0, 'width': 117, 'height': 106, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.626}, {'x': 446.0, 'y': 189.0, 'width': 124, 'height': 130, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.528}]

confidence_1 = lst[0]['confidence']
confidence_2 = lst[1]['confidence']

# 0.626
# 0.528
```

Or:

```
lst = [{'x': 403.5, 'y': 53.0, 'width': 117, 'height': 106, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.626}, {'x': 446.0, 'y': 189.0, 'width': 124, 'height': 130, 'class': 'fruitflies', 'confidence': 0.528}]

for c in lst: print(c['confidence'])

# 0.626
# 0.528
```